# Giving partcular ctags kinds the priority

Tags: c++, vim, ctags

I use `vim+ctags` with C++ and I'd like `:tag` to jump to class definition *by default*, rather than its constructor. In other words, I'd like to give the "c" (class) kind higher priority than the "f" one.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I use vim 7.1 and exuberant ctags 5.7

Comment: Just to confirm: you're using Exuberant ctags, right? And which language? C++?